# Dockerfile not creating selfsigned Cert

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have the following Dockerfile.  It is supposed to create the selfsigned cert when I first build the image.  Then letsencrypt should auto renew it.  The issue that I am having is that the cert never gets created.  When I run the exact openssl command on the /etc/apache2/certificate directory manually it works, but something is off on Dockerfile.  When call the docker file I see that it creates the key in red letters, but never writes it to the dir.  What am I missing?

```
FROM php:7.4.3-apache
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y apt-utils libhtml-template-pro-perl default-mysql-client libtemplate-perl openssl
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql && docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql
RUN mkdir /ztp_data
RUN a2enmod ssl
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN mkdir /etc/apache2/certificate
RUN cd /etc/apache2/certificate
RUN openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -x509 -sha256 -days 365 -nodes -out apache-certificate.crt -keyout apache.key -subj "/C=US/ST=GA/L=Atlanta/O=CompanyABC/CN=`hostname -f`"
RUN sleep 20
RUN service apache2 restart
```

Comment: `RUN cd ...` doesn't do anything, the next `RUN` line will start over at whatever the current `WORKDIR` is (possibly `/`).  Is the certificate getting created but in a different place than you expect?

Comment: changed RUN to WORKDIR and still the cert does not get created.  When I run docker I see the that it is generating the cert in RED without any errors, but not sure why it is creating the cert.

Comment: @CoeurjoliMartinez : I answered you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67693043/unable-to-write-to-dir-using-dockerfile/67708709#67708709) consider accept if solved