# unable to write to dir using Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have the following Dockerfile.  I am tried to rebuild the image and from docker-compose using --build argument.  I see it going through the steps including recreating the cert, but it does not write it to the dir.  The directory is owned by root and root has full access to it.  I am running docker-compose as root as well.  This is a mounted directory on /var/lib/docker/volumes.  The /etc/apache2/certificate dir exists.  What am I missing?

```
--DockerFile
    FROM php:7.4.3-apache
    RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y apt-utils libhtml-template-pro-perl default-mysql-client libtemplate-perl openssl
    RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql && docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql
    RUN a2enmod ssl
    RUN a2enmod rewrite
    WORKDIR /etc/apache2/certificate
    RUN touch testing_before.txt
    RUN openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -x509 -sha256 -days 365 -nodes -out apache-certificate.crt -keyout apache.key -subj "/C=US/ST=GA/L=Atlanta/O=Companyabc/CN=`hostname -f`"
    RUN touch testing_after.txt
    RUN service apache2 restart

---Docker-compose
---
version: "3.7"
services:
  web:
    build: ./apache 
    container_name: apache
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - web-data:/var/www/html
      - web-conf:/etc/apache2
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
volumes:
  web-data:
  web-conf:
```

Comment: Which directory are you looking at?  How are you looking at it?  Whatever's in the `web-conf` named volume will take precedence over the self-signed certificate that gets recreated during the build; Docker considers named volumes to generally contain important user data and you don't need a volume to keep things that are part of the underlying image.

Comment: I am looking at it from the host.  looking at directory /var/lib/docker/volumes/lamp_web-conf/_data/certificate.  It is empty.

Comment: @CoeurjoliMartinez if solved [consider](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251288/dealing-with-an-answer-that-wasnt-accepted-maybe-because-a-user-is-a-newbie-on/251298#251298)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> RUN openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -x509 -sha256 -days 365 -nodes
> -out apache-certificate.crt -keyout apache.key -subj "/C=US/ST=GA/L=Atlanta/O=Companyabc/CN=`hostname -f`"

It doesn’t make sense to have a hostname in build phase in most of the time, by setting the hostname within the `RUN` command similar to how you installed packages using `apt-get`, it happen inside the same layer of the container. Docker will later overwrite the hostname  as Docker daemon sets the hostname dynamically at runtime.

**Probably below snippet you can use in your `Dockerfile`**

```
# base image
FROM php:7.4.3-apache

# your other packages & extensions goes here
# .....

# ports you expose here
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

# override your entrypoint with new script
ADD docker-entrypoint.sh /

# make it executable
RUN chmod a+x /docker-entrypoint.sh

# your new entry point override
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

# we're using original apache2-foreground script

CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

and create `docker-entrypoint.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

# if you have some more task put here
# example configuration customisation etc..

# certificate directory
mkdir -p /etc/apache2/certificate

if [ ! -f "/etc/apache2/certificate/apache-certificate.crt" ] || [ ! -f "/etc/apache2/certificate/apache.key" ]; then
  echo ">> generating self signed cert"
  openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 \
  -subj "/C=US/ST=GA/L=Atlanta/O=Companyabc/CN=`hostname -f`" \
  -keyout "/etc/apache2/certificate/apache.key" \
  -out "/etc/apache2/certificate/apache-certificate.crt" \
  -days 365 -nodes -sha256
 
fi

# first arg is `-f` or `--some-option`
if [ "${1#-}" != "$1" ]; then
    set -- apache2-foreground "$@"
fi

exec "$@"
```

[You can refer original entrypoint here](https://github.com/docker-library/php/tree/47e681a74116da5a99e804bef5a7808df40d831f/7.4/buster/apache)

and you can set hostname inside your web service container

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  web:
    build: ./apache 
    container_name: apache
    hostname: web-server.mydomain.com
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - web-data:/var/www/html
      - web-conf:/etc/apache2
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
volumes:
  web-data:
  web-conf:
```

**Test Results:**

```
root@sys:/home/akshay/Documents/test# tree 
.
├── apache
│   ├── docker-entrypoint.sh
│   └── Dockerfile
└── docker-compose.yml

1 directory, 3 files
root@sys:/home/akshay/Documents/test# docker-compose up -d --build
Building web
Step 1/7 : FROM php:7.4.3-apache
 ---> d753d5b380a1
Step 2/7 : EXPOSE 80
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 66c155b818cc
Step 3/7 : EXPOSE 443
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 141789b7ce40
Step 4/7 : ADD docker-entrypoint.sh /
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0fd8d03fb8ec
Step 5/7 : RUN chmod a+x /docker-entrypoint.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9a081cf61816
Step 6/7 : ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 22b1851f7882
Step 7/7 : CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 46c5cf7c6630

Successfully built 46c5cf7c6630
Successfully tagged test_web:latest
apache is up-to-date

root@sys:/home/akshay/Documents/test# docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE      COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                                                      NAMES
20a2af0e0570   test_web   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   50 seconds ago   Up 48 seconds   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, :::443->443/tcp   apache

root@web-server:/var/www/html# ls /etc/apache2/certificate/ -1
apache-certificate.crt
apache.key

root@web-server:/var/www/html# openssl x509 -in /etc/apache2/certificate/apache-certificate.crt -text | head -15
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            5f:b9:28:da:06:53:12:64:c3:e5:1c:90:5d:9e:18:f5:f2:1f:2c:eb
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = US, ST = GA, L = Atlanta, O = Companyabc, CN = web-server.mydomain.com
        Validity
            Not Before: May 26 16:45:25 2021 GMT
            Not After : May 26 16:45:25 2022 GMT
        Subject: C = US, ST = GA, L = Atlanta, O = Companyabc, CN = web-server.mydomain.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (4096 bit)
                Modulus:
```

**To ensure recreation of certificate**

```
root@sys:/home/akshay/Documents/test# docker-compose up -d  --force-recreate
Recreating apache ... done
root@sys:/home/akshay/Documents/test# docker exec -it apache bash
root@web-server:/var/www/html#  openssl x509 -in /etc/apache2/certificate/apache-certificate.crt -text | head -15
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            43:1a:6d:c1:af:bc:05:54:58:04:f7:d2:42:d7:92:5f:ef:dc:a6:20
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = US, ST = GA, L = Atlanta, O = Companyabc, CN = web-server.mydomain.com
        Validity
            Not Before: May 26 16:53:34 2021 GMT
            Not After : May 26 16:53:34 2022 GMT
        Subject: C = US, ST = GA, L = Atlanta, O = Companyabc, CN = web-server.mydomain.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (4096 bit)
                Modulus:
```